# How to get the same MD5 string in Java as in C#

Tags: java, c#

I have code in C# which produces MD5 encoded `byte[]` from `String` and then this `byte[]` is converted to `String`. The C# code is

```
byte[] valueBytes = (new UnicodeEncoding()).GetBytes(value);
byte[] newHash = (new MD5CryptoServiceProvider()).ComputeHash(valueBytes);
```

I need to get the same result in Java. I'm trying to do this

```
Charset utf16 = Charset.forName("UTF-16");
return new String(DigestUtils.md5(value.getBytes(utf16)), utf16);
```

The code is using Apache Commons Codec library for MD5 calculations. I'm using UTF16 charset because I've read in other SO questions that C#'s `UnicodeEncoding` uses it by default.

So the code snippets look like they do the same thing, but when I'm passing the string `byndyusoft2014`, C# gives me `hV7u6mQYRgBXXF9jOWWYJg==` and Java gives me `﹡둛뭶魙ꇥ늺ꢑ`. I've tried UTF16LE and UTF16BE as charsets with no luck.

Has anyone idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `C# gives me hV7u6mQYRgBXXF9jOWWYJg==` No your code returns byte array. You convert it somewhere to base64 string. Do the same in hava too

Comment: What is `byndyusoft2014`? You shouldn't create a string out of the MD5 hash value bytes directly. You can use the `md5Hex()` method or the `Base64` class to get a string representation for the bytes. And you should use the same type of string representation for the hash bytes in both languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the main difference was not presented in my original code snippet - it was convertation from MD5 encoded `byte[]` to `String`. You need to use Base64 to get final result. This is the working code snippet in Java

```
Charset utf16 = Charset.forName("UTF-16LE");
return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(DigestUtils.md5(value.getBytes(utf16))));
```

With this code I get the same result as with C#. Thank you all for good hints!

Answer (score 1):

I think because of the java decode string to byte[] with `utf-8`,but the C# is not.So the java and C# encode the different byte array,and then get the different result.You can decode the string to byte[] at c# with utf-8,and see the result.Like following code:

```
UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
byte[] bytes=utf8.GetBytes("byndyusoft2014");
byte[] en=(new MD5CryptoServiceProvider()).ComputeHash(bytes);
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(en));
```

and the java code:

```
    byte[] en = DigestUtils.md5Digest("byndyusoft2014".getBytes());
    byte[] base64 = Base64Utils.encode(en);
    System.out.println(new String(base64));
```

Of course,in your description,the result of C# like be encoded with base64,so the java should encode the byte array with base64.
The result of them is same as `swPvmbGDI1GbPKQwL9knjQ==`

The `DigestUtils` and `Base64Utils` is some implementation of `MD5` and `BAS64` in spring library

Comment: Thank you for the hint with Base64. It solved the problem.